# PHP - Pull single value out of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP multidimensional array on a WP site that I'm trying to get a single value from. I looked at other solutions on here, but can't seem to get them to work. Wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code, I'm trying to get the post title out of the first entry (for example):

```
<?php echo $array[0]['furniture_item']['post_title']; ?>
```

It just breaks the page and nothing else past it loads.

Here's the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [furniture_item] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 585
                    [post_title] => C4
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [furniture_item] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 619
                    [post_title] => L2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [furniture_item] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 195
                    [post_title] => C1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [furniture_item] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 600
                    [post_title] => C10
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `$array[0]['furniture_item']` is an object not an array

Comment: `$array[0]['furniture_item']->post_title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `furniture_item` is an object, so you need to use the `->` syntax to get that `post_title` out of it. Like so:

```
<?php echo $array[0]['furniture_item']->post_title; ?>
```

As for it not displaying anything on the site after your error code, it's because you don't have `WP_DEBUG` turned on. Put this in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

PHP should then actually generate errors and tell you what went wrong. [Read this for more on that](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG).